# Why is the potential difference the same on all points in AND on a conductor the same?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, electrical-resistance, conductors

I'm wondering why the potential difference in the inside of the conductor (beneath the surface) and the surface of the conductor is the same.

Comment: A potential difference is always between two points, not at one. Can you try to explain more concisely what you mean?

Comment: The P.D is zero for static E on the conductor and on its surface.

Comment: Sharpen your question a bit because the electric field inside a conductor is 0 (in equilibrium)meaning that the potential is at most a constant. On the surface though  we do have charge and therefore we have a non zero electric field so the potential will be different.

Answer (score 1):

The question would make more sense when removing the word "difference", which I assume here. In that case the answer is because when the eletrostatic equilibrium is reached, all free charges within the conductor find their place on the boundary of the conductor in such a way that the electric potential is constant it the whole conductor. If it was not the case, then the charges would move because of a non-zero electric field, condradicting the equilibrium assumption. The potential being continuous up to the boundary, it has the same constant value inside *and* on the boundary of the conductor.

Comment: Would it be possible to further detail ? You say "the charges would move" but what if there are no charges right there but somewhere else where the potential is indeed constant ? I have in mind a situation where there is a particle inside the conductor but in a place where the gradient of the potential is the zero vector (say, if the potential is constant inside the conductor except over some volume not containing the particle), as opposed to other areas where I'm assuming it isn't. Why can't that be an equilibrium ?